# c# fail to match class with generic (that is constrained to interface) with a class that inherits and sets the generic to a class with the interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to implement code with generics and interfaces in unity ([so c# 9.0](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html)) the code can mostly be broken down to:

```cs
using System;

public interface ITest { }
public class BaseTestContainer<T> where T : ITest { }
public class TestObject : ITest { }
public class TestContainer : BaseTestContainer<TestObject> { }

public class Bar {
    private BaseTestContainer<ITest> _container;

    public void Call(BaseTestContainer<ITest> testContainer) {
        Console.WriteLine($"test Container: {testContainer}, is null: {testContainer == null}");
        _container = testContainer;
    }
}

public class Foo<T> where T : ITest {
    public void Call(BaseTestContainer<T> testContainer) {
        new Bar().Call(testContainer);
    }

    public void Call2(BaseTestContainer<T> testContainer) {
        new Bar().Call(testContainer as BaseTestContainer<ITest>);
    }

    public void Call3(BaseTestContainer<T> testContainer) {
        if (testContainer is BaseTestContainer<ITest> container) {
            new Bar().Call(container);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Foo.Call raises the error: Argument type 'BaseTestContainer' is not assignable to parameter type 'BaseTestContainer'

Foo.Call2 give null as argument to Bar.Call.

Foo.Call3 prints "No"

Shouldn't BaseTestContainer where T: ITest match BaseTestContainer? What am I missing here? Is there an other way to accomplish this?

I tried the call methods I posted and some more. AI was no help. I expect that I can send the the implemented class of the generic class to Bar and use it there.

Comment: This is a fairly common misunderstanding of how generics works. You probably want to add a covariant interface for your `BaseTestContainer` , see [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) for more details.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I saw Covariance and Contravariance in my search, 
but now it clicked.  

Solution for this example:  
- split up Container (with out or in, depending on what you need):
`public interface IBaseTestContainer<out T> where T : ITest { }
public class BaseTestContainer<T> : IBaseTestContainer<T> where T : ITest { }`
- replace BaseTestContainer with IBaseTestContainer in Bar.  
- in Foo.Call you can cast the testContainer:  
`new Bar().Call((IBaseTestContainer<ITest>)testContainer);`